# Does My Readiness Rating Change the Ending if it Decreases While I'm in the Last Mission

Tags: mass-effect-3

I was able to push my effective rating over 4000 before I started the final assault on Earth and received the "Master and Commander" trophy.  I then got to just after you are beamed up to the Citadel and saved.  Due to some personal issues I didn't get back to the game and now my Readiness rating is down to 60% (which BTW is the worst "feature" of this game).  Does anyone know if my effective rating was "locked" in when I started the assault or do I need to grind it back up to 80%?

It's also annoying you can't find this data without being on Normandy.  :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ending based on your readiness level is locked in at the beginning of *Priority: Cerberus Headquarters*.  For the "best" endings your readiness rating needs to be over 4000; the percent is not what is important.

You can reply each of the endings at the "locked" readiness level from an auto-save that will become available after you finish once.  If you wish to raise your readiness level further, you'll need to restart before *Priority: Cerberus Headquarters*.

Source: http://www.ign.com/wikis/mass-effect-3/Endings

The above link also provides a breakdown of the differences between the endings.  Once you complete the game you can check your ending against the table to verify that you saw what you think you should have seen.